# Redirect iOS app console.log to the Terminal

Tags: ios, bash, logging, fastlane

Is there any known method to redirect `console.log()` from a iOS app, running in a simulator, to a Mac Terminal?

For example when building and testing my project, in the Terminal via `[fastlane][1] scan`, I'd like to see all my custom `console.log` to be printed in the Terminal.

Is that possible?

Comment: printed in the `bash` you mean on the console you are running the command? By default when running the command, you don't see anything on the console?

Comment: By bash I mean the Mac bash when for example building/testing an app with Fastlane. There is no app-internal (i.e. NSLog, print, etc.) log output by default.

Comment: As @Inian said, the default output is the same bash shell you launch fastlane.

By "Mac bash" you mean Xcode log? (I interpreted because you mean NSLog)

Please, explain better what you want to achieve, because it's confusing and we could not help you :/

Comment: I have updated the question with better explanation of the request (I have exactly the same need). Basically what we need is that all our `console.log()` are printed in to the Terminal.app from where we ran a command in order to execute the app tests.

Comment: Check out `os_log`. It will accomplish what you're attempting - and is way more performant.

Comment: Hey @OscarApeland can you give more about `os_log`? I searched a bit and found nothing interesting about `os_log` and react-native.

Comment: @ZedTuX I first learned of it from this years WWDC State of the Union, you can check that out on Apples site and go from there :)

Comment: @OscarApeland I just watched the WWDC SOTU, and especially the `os_log` part. It sounds like a Switf thing. Here, we are working with react-native and javascript, so no `os_log` but `console.log()`. Can you confirm what I said or correct me please?

Comment: @ZedTuX Yea, it's a Swift thing, sorry about that. I didn't catch that you were using JS. I sadly do not have enough knowledge of React Native to help you out further.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

I first through about the `react-native log-ios` in a separated terminal, while my tests are running (using Fastlane), but it didn't work.

What is working for me is to enable the remote debugger, and keep Chrome opened on the debugger's page (http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/), like when developing, and it is working, you get the logs here.

Comment: Try `react-native-log-ios` npm package maybe

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would use `react-native log-ios` in a terminal, but this command has been broken since version 0.5x...
You can work around this:

```
npm i -g react-native-log-ios
react-native-log-ios <XCode Project Name>
```